# How to integreate two codes with delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

i have this code to animate my page with anchors

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
```

And this other code to make a delay when the link is presed

```
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 500 );
}
```

So when i have a link with `<a href="#demo">demo</a>` the first code runs perfeclty but when i add the delay like this `<a onclick="delay ('#contentexpand-1')">demo</a>` the first code doesn't work just jump to the anchor.

Please help me! thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your animation is attached to `<a>` tags. That does not get triggered when you simply set the window location. The solution is to trigger the animate both ways:

```
// Smoothly scroll to a tag defined by <a name="anchorName">
function scrollTo (anchorName) {
    $('html, body').animate( {
        scrollTop: $( "a[name=" + anchorName + "]" ).offset().top
    }, 500);
}

// Make all # anchors scroll smoothly to their targets
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
        var anchorName = $(this).attr('href').substr(1); // strip off #
        scrollTo(anchorName);
        return false;
    });
});

// Scroll to an anchor after half a second
function delay (anchorName) {
    setTimeout( function() { scrollTo(anchorName); }, 500 );
}
```

I am not convinced that your code for finding the offset was right so I adjusted it a bit to make it clearer.

The tag you want to scroll to is defined like this:

```
<a name="demo">demo</a>
```

Then you can choose either behaviour:

```
<a href="#demo">scroll smoothly to demo immediately</a>
<a onclick="delay ('demo')">scroll smoothly to demo after half second delay</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! but when i put your code firebug show me this TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined  `scrollTop: $( "a[name=" + anchorName + "]" ).offset().top` so my anchors doesn't scroll smoothly

Comment: Funnily enough, that's exactly the error I got when I tried to use your code. Try your animate code with the functions I suggested? :)